# How in Google Forms add Timer?

Tags: google-forms

Is it possible to add a timer in Google Form? Please tell me how to implement this.

Comment: This doesn't look to be a programming question. Please checkout [ask].

Answer (score -1):

As far as I'm aware that isn't available in Google forms. Try using a test making service like [www.moodle.org](http://www.moodle.org). Or if you want to specifically use Google forms here's a timing tutorial https://www.labnol.org/internet/schedule-google-forms/20707/

Comment: Almost the same, it is necessary that when the form is opened there is a countdown, for example 10 minutes, at the end of time, so that the form is closed. And so every time you open